Authorization token when using Feign client
I have two services api-gateway and auth. Api-gateway has bean RouteLocator that has router to auth. My goal to assess to auth serverby using FeignClient to check is token is valid.
Here ServiceFeignClient in api-gateway
@FeignClient(name = "auth-server", url = "http://localhost:8088")
@Headers("Authorization: {token}")
public interface ServiceFeignClient {

    String AUTH_TOKEN = "Authorization";

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
     String test(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
} 

And RestController in auth:
@RestController
public class TokenController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        ///logic
    }
}

When I add in auth-server in SecurityConfig:
 auth.requestMatchers("/test").permitAll();

it works, so I have made a mistake when token is sent. Otherwise, I get 401 error
